# Proof check regarding equivalent definitions of $\omega$-limit sets

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, solution-verification, dynamical-systems

While studying Dynamical systems, more specifically, $\omega$-limit sets, I came across two different definitions

**Definition 1:**
For a sequence of points $\left\{x_n\right\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$, the $\omega$-limit set of $\left\{x_n\right\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is given as the set of accumulation points of the sequence. It is formally defined as
$$
\omega\left(\left\{x_n\right\}\right)=\bigcap_{n=0}^{\infty} \overline{\left\{x_k: k \geq n\right\}}
$$
In particular, if $\left\{x_n\right\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is the orbit of a point $x \in X$ for a map $f: X \rightarrow X$, we define the $\omega$-limit set of $x$ (under $f$ ) as
$$
\omega(x, f)=\bigcap_{n=0}^{\infty} \overline{\left\{f^k(x): k \geq n\right\}}
$$
This definition was taken from https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/11034.pdf

**Definition 2:**
The cluster set of $\left\{x_n\right\}_{n=0}^{\infty}$ is the set of subsequential limit points of $\left\{x_n\right\}_{n=0}^{\infty}$

Let $f$ be a continuous function. The ${\omega-l i m i t}$ set (some authors use the term "attractor set") $\omega(x, f)$ is defined to be the cluster set of $\left\{f^n(x)\right\}_{n=0}^{\infty}$

This definition was taken from https://www.researchgate.net/publication/265579797_The_structure_of_o-limit_sets_for_continuous_maps_of_the_interval

I am trying to prove **(1)** and **(2)** are equivalent.

**Proposition:**
\begin{equation}
\omega(x)=\bigcap_{n=0}^{\infty} \overline{\left\{f^k(x): k \geq n\right\}}
\end{equation}

**Attempt:**
Let $y \in \omega(x)$. Then, there exists a subsequence such that:
\begin{equation}
\lim _{k \rightarrow \infty} f^{n_k}(x)=y
\end{equation}
We observe that, for every $n_{k} \geq k$, it follows that $f^{n_{k}}(x) \in {\left\{f^k(x): k \geq n\right\}}$. Therefore, $y \in \overline{\left\{f^k(x): k \geq n\right\}}$, since $y$ is the limit of a sequence of points in $\left\{f^k(x): k \geq n\right\}$.

**Now, for the converse, let**
\begin{equation}
y \in \bigcap_{n=0}^{\infty} \overline{\left\{f^k(x) \mid k \geqslant n\right\}}
\end{equation}

then, by definition, it must follow that:

\begin{equation}
y \in \overline{\left\{f^k(x) \mid k \geqslant n\right\}}, \forall n \in \mathbb{N}
\end{equation}

From the definition of closure, there exists a sequence $\alpha_{n}$ of points in $\left\{f^k(x) \mid k \geq n\right\}$ such that it converges to $y$. From the definition of the prior set, we must have:

\begin{equation}
\lim _{k \rightarrow \infty} f^k(x)=y, \forall k \geq n
\end{equation}

Since the sequence converges to $y$, every subsequence must converge to the same limit, which yields:

\begin{equation}
\lim _{l \rightarrow \infty} f^{k_l}(x)=y, \forall k_l \geq n
\end{equation}

**Definitions:**
Let $X \subset \mathbb{R}$ and $y \in \overline X$. Then, there exists a sequence of points $y_{n} \in X$ such that $y_{n} \rightarrow y$.

Can someone provide feedback regarding my proof? If it is wrong, how could I fix it?

Thanks very much in advance, Lucas